# How to tell if a page has subpages for Custom Post Types

Tags: php, pages, archives

I would like to show a page depending on whether it has a subpage or not.

That is, if you have subpages, do not display the subpages, only the parent page to which it belongs.

Something like this:

```
Books of science
  Book 1
  Book 2
```

---

```
Books of science fiction
  Book 1
  Book 2
```

I have a home page where I want to show all the books, that is, all the main pages:

```
Books of science
Books of science fiction
```

And the idea is, not to show the subpages because it doesn't make sense in my case.

Is it possible?

Comment: Could you give an example? First part of your question was clear, but then you lost me ;) What do you mean by "if you have subpages, do not display the subpages, only the parent page to which it belongs"?

Comment: If it's a little confusing now that I've read it again, I just edited the question

Answer (score 0):

This code will return an array with IDs of all pages having sub pages. Hope you were looking for it :)

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);
$parentPages = array(); // an empty array to store pages with childs
$pages = get_pages($args); 
// Looping through all pages and then we'll check for the pages with child
foreach($pages as $page) {
    if($page->post_parent != 0){ // checking if the page has any parent
        // checking if parent page isn't in our array already
        if(!in_array($page->post_parent, $parentPages)) { 
            array_push($parentPages, $page->post_parent);
        }
    }
}
print_r($parentPages);
```

Comment: Well.. It won't. It will do nothing more than generate some warnings and notices - `$pages` and `$parentPages` variables are not defined anywhere, so...

Comment: just added the loop code also. hope it helps now.